# Finding the distribution through random number generation in R

Tags: r, quantile, exponential-distribution

`X` is exponentially distributed with parameter `lambda=0.5`.
I want to find `Pr(1/mean(X)< K)=0.95`
As I don't know the distribution of `1/mean(X)` I generate a distribution by the following code.

```
m<-c()
exponentialFunc<-function(n,lambda,nsim){
    for(i in seq(nsim)){
    x<-rexp(n,lambda)
    y<-mean(x)
    m<-c(m,1/y)
    }
    m

}
```

Now `m` is the distribution of `1/mean(x)`.
Now I called this function by `exponentialFunc(10,0.5,10000)` and it gives a series of values for m.
But then as I want to find the quantile of this distribution which has a probability of 0.95 when I used `quantile(m,0.95)` the output is

`> quantile(m,0.95)
95% 
 NA`
Why does it produces `NA`? Is there anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you didn't save the output of your function in an object named `m`:

```
> m <- exponentialFunc(10,0.5,10000)
> quantile(m,0.95)
     95% 
0.939102
```

You are calling your function and not saving it anywhere, it seems that what you are doing is (basically) this:

```
> m<-c()
> quantile(m,0.95)
95% 
 NA
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Alternatively, one can pass the function output directly as an argument: `quantile(exponentialFunc(10,0.5,10000),0.95)`.